# send email core django VS Sendgrid

Tags: django, sendgrid

Maybe this is a silly question, but basically what is the difference between use the core email library in django vs Sendgrid? and in advance way what is the difference too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sendgrid is SMTP provider (i.e. like gmail) and Django's library is used to connect to SMTP provider. So you need both to actually send email.